# Rubymine doens't understand that index.html.erb is html file

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, rubymine

When I create index.html.erb file in my project, Rubymine doesn't understand that it is HTML file - it has text file icon and none syntax highlight.

But if I'll rename it, everything will be alright! Other .html.erb files are recognized correctly.
Rubymine 7.0.4

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `Preferences... -> Editor -> File Types`. One from these file types has `index.html.erb` pattern. You should find it and remove.

Seems like you have added it by mistake.